# With XML query using R and XPath 1.0, unable to extract specific text

Tags: html, xml, r, parsing, xpath

I would greatly appreciate guidance on how I can extract the four names of cities where this firm has offices.  Firebug has the name greyed-out under cufontext, such as `<cufontext>MEMPHIS</cufontext>` and MEMPHIS is in grey.  BTW, I don't mind getting some extraneous text back such as state or address.  Three of my failed efforts are shown.

```
library(XML)

doc <- htmlTreeParse('http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/', useInternal = TRUE, asText = TRUE)               
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'the_content']", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)  # returns list()
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'the_content']/div/h3//cufon", xmlValue, trim = TRUE) # returns NULL
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'the_content']//cufon[@class = 'cufon cufon-canvas']", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)  # returns NULL
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, `rl <- readLines(url); htmlTreeParse(rl, asText = TRUE)` seems to work.

Comment: @RichardScriven: Thanks.  Getting the HTML from the site is not the problem.  The XPath expression to extract the cities is what has blocked me and the suggested answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the HTML source actually looks about like this (formatted & simplified) :

```
<div id="the_content">
    <div class="one_fourth">
        <h3>KNOXVILLE</h3>
        <p>One Centre Square, Fifth Floor<br>
        .....
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

but browsers (tried using chrome and firefox) somehow transform it to a slightly different structure, while the parser doesn't do the transformation. This simpler XPath worked fine for me :

```
//div[@id = 'the_content']/div/h3
```

Comment: thank you.  If I copy the HTML source from Firebug, do I use the {} operation here in SO to format it like yours (red for attributes, blue for 'element' and indented?

Comment: > doc <- htmlTreeParse('http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/', useInternal = TRUE, asText = TRUE)               
> xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'the_content']/div/h3", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
NULL

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with `R`, only know XPath. Anyway, after looking at [xmlTreeParse()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/XML/docs/xmlTreeParse) documentation (can't find documentation for `htmlTreeParse()` anywhere), `asText=TRUE` will cause the parser to treat you url as HTML (try to print `doc` variable to confirm this).

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, @har07, but it doesn't work, as shown in my comment above.

Comment: why you need to set `asText=TRUE` this time? I really suspect that causes a problem

Comment: if I omit asText=TRUE, I get an error: Error: failed to load HTTP resource.  I can use httr with this call: doc <- content(GET('http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/')) but your suggested XPath expression returns NULL